# Why does Dart FFI generate an opaque class from this C struct?

Tags: c, dart, ffi, mavlink, dart-ffi

I want to use the [MAVLink C library](https://github.com/mavlink/c_library_v2) to parse MAVLink packets in dart, but the Dart FFI generated mavlink_message_t is an opaque class, while other structs like mavlink_system_t are generated normally with all their attributes. What is the reason for this behaviour, and how can I fix it?

mavlink_message_t C struct

```c
MAVPACKED(
typedef struct __mavlink_message {
    uint16_t checksum;      ///< sent at end of packet
    uint8_t magic;          ///< protocol magic marker
    uint8_t len;            ///< Length of payload
    uint8_t incompat_flags; ///< flags that must be understood
    uint8_t compat_flags;   ///< flags that can be ignored if not understood
    uint8_t seq;            ///< Sequence of packet
    uint8_t sysid;          ///< ID of message sender system/aircraft
    uint8_t compid;         ///< ID of the message sender component
    uint32_t msgid:24;      ///< ID of message in payload
    uint64_t payload64[(MAVLINK_MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN+MAVLINK_NUM_CHECKSUM_BYTES+7)/8];
    uint8_t ck[2];          ///< incoming checksum bytes
    uint8_t signature[MAVLINK_SIGNATURE_BLOCK_LEN];
}) mavlink_message_t;
```

mavlink_system_t C struct

```c
MAVPACKED(
typedef struct __mavlink_system {
    uint8_t sysid;   ///< Used by the MAVLink message_xx_send() convenience function
    uint8_t compid;  ///< Used by the MAVLink message_xx_send() convenience function
}) mavlink_system_t;
```

FFI generated Dart classes

```c
class mavlink_message_t extends ffi.Opaque {}

@ffi.Packed(1)
class mavlink_system_t extends ffi.Struct {
  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int sysid;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int compid;
}
```

Comment: `ffigen` is probably confused by one of the fields and gives up - I'm guessing `payload` or `msgid`. Try removing parts until it generates better and you'll know which syntax is breaking it. That will help you work around (or open an issue).

Comment: Thanks, the culprit was msgid:24, since Dart FFI doesn't support bit fields yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Richard Heap 's comment, I found out the source of this issue was the `msgid:24` field definition. Since it's a [bit field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), which [isn't currently supported](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38954) by Dart FFI, ffigen generates an opaque class definition from it. After removing the `msgid:24` declaration, instead of ffi.Opaque, an ffi.Struct was generated

```c
@ffi.Packed(1)
class mavlink_message_t extends ffi.Struct {
  @ffi.Uint16()
  external int checksum;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int magic;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int len;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int incompat_flags;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int compat_flags;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int seq;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int sysid;

  @ffi.Uint8()
  external int compid;

  @ffi.Array.multi([33])
  external ffi.Array<ffi.Uint64> payload64;

  @ffi.Array.multi([2])
  external ffi.Array<ffi.Uint8> ck;

  @ffi.Array.multi([13])
  external ffi.Array<ffi.Uint8> signature;
}
```

This of course is not enough since I need all the fields, but there is a [workaround](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/75bee2083af461f21aced9e87b0d0559a038e618/samples/ffi/sample_ffi_bitfield.dart) for this which I'll test.